# SSRS 2005 parameters not returning any results when null checked

Tags: checkbox, reporting-services

newbie to SSRS, running 2005.  I hope someone can help!

I have a report with a parameter on it, `ItemNum`.  I have it as a string, to *allow NULL value*  and *allow blank value*, nothing in Available values, and *null* selected for Default Values.  I then have in there `WHERE` part of my `SELECT` statement `where item_num IN (@ItemNum)`.

when I preview the report, I get NO results if I:

leave the NULL checkbox checked (and obviously the Item # parameter empty, it's greyed out) or
uncheck the NULL checkbox but don't put a value in the parameter.

the ONLY way I can get ANY results back is to enter a valid item number.

I would think that if you *Allow Null values* and/or *Allow Blank values*, it should just disregard that parameter.  Perhaps it's because of it being in the `where` clause?

how can I make this function the way I need it to, i.e. if the NULL checkbox is checked (or unchecked and NO value entered) disregard that parameter (or in other words, return all records)?

also -- as a 2nd question -- is it possible to use the `LIKE` comparison with a parameter or does it always have to be `IN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE @ItemNum is null OR item_num IN (@ItemNum)
```

You need to explicitly check for `NULL` in this case.

In fact, why are you using `IN` for a single value?  It's usually used to check for a number of values, e.g. `WHERE item_num IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 10)`.  A simple `=` would suffice.

Comment: Sir Crispalot -- THANK YOU!!!  :)   and I changed it to = .  The reason I had IN was because I actually have several other parameters (like customer #) that I do a query to build all the possible customers to choose from, so those were IN's. For my other question, I have a parameter for customer PO # and I have it as "where cust_po_num LIKE (@PONum)" and want to be able to do wildcard lookups.Unless I default a "%" in the parameter, no results are returned once again.I know the users will forget that the character has to be in there.Is there a way to tell the param to put a "%" in if blank?

Comment: Should ask a separate question, but you could concatenate: `LIKE ('%' + @PONum)`

Comment: #Sir Crispalot -- you rock :)  Thank you again for your invaluable help.  Sending you a cyber thank you kiss :)

Comment: I would be most happy to -- but how do I do that?  (new to this forum!)